# the word for an object that has a name that doesn't describe it

Tags: meaning, word-choice

the word for an object that has a name that doesn't describe it

for example;

prospect park
in this case; the name actually does describe the thing (location) 
lets pretend that it didn't
like
bourough park

Answer (score 2):

> misnomer

Per Google's definitions:

*A wrong or inaccurate name or designation.*

*"“king crab” is a misnomer—these creatures are not crustaceans at all"*

Synonyms:   inaccurate name/label/designation, wrong name/label/designation, inappropriate name/label/designation

[wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misnomer)